# Can Sequel be forced to always return autoincrement id with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, ruby, sequel, on-duplicate-key

I'm working with Sequel (4.x) and MySQL 5.5, on a write-heavy application performing mostly `INSERT`s and occasionally updating existing rows. Sequel returns an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id following an `.insert()` action.

I'm currently using `.on_duplicate_key_update()` in an expression like:

```
# Insert new row into cache_table, updating any columns that change
# on a key violation
id = DB[:table_name].on_duplicate_key_update.insert(
  col1: @col1,
  col2: @col2,
  created: nil,
  updated: nil
)
```

This returns the auto-increment id (`LAST_INSERT_ID()`) into the variable `id` when the row is newly inserted or a column's value changes, but returns `0` if no column's value is modified.

Reading [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), I understand why. When performing a MySQL `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, MySQL cannot reliably return the `AUTO_INCREMENT` id of a row that already existed but was unchanged by the `UPDATE`.  The docs suggest using an `UPDATE` expression like:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`id`)
```

I would really like to avoid an additional `SELECT` in this particular application. How can I force Sequel to use the same behavior, and always return the row `id` even absent any actual changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to cause Sequel to execute a function on the RDBMS using the [`Sequel.function()` method](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/dataset_filtering_rdoc.html#label-Specifying+SQL+functions)

To execute MySQL's native `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and pass the column `id` as its argument, pass the column name as a symbol as the second argument:

```
Sequel.function(:last_insert_id, :id)
```

The [`Dataset#on_duplicate_key_update` method](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/MySQL/DatasetMethods.html#method-i-on_duplicate_key_update) accepts a hash of columns and new values for update, so the `:last_insert_id` function may be passed there, along with an explicit listing of other columns to update:

```
id = DB[:table_name].on_duplicate_key_update(
  # Call the native LAST_INSERT_ID()
  id: Sequel.function(:last_insert_id, :id),
  col1: @col1,
  col2: @col2,
  updated: nil
).insert(
  col1: @col1,
  col2: @col2,
  created: nil,
  updated: nil
)
```

This method reliably returns the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` into `id`, without needing to do a `SELECT` query.

**Note**: `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` *will* cause the table's `AUTO_INCREMENT` value to advance when rows are updated if the table contains any additional `UNIQUE` index besides the `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key. This isn't specific to Sequel, just a general warning when using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

If this is not acceptable, you may need to resort to doing a separate `SELECT` instead to retrieve the id when `DB.insert()` returns `0`.